# Is it possible to find what Matrix Block aren't being used

Tags: entries, matrix

I have a fairly large site with the main content on most pages driven by a Matrix field. That Matrix field has 15 or so different Blocks - we are now doing a tidy up on the site and going to try and reduce the number of blocks available - is there any way to tell if a block isn't being used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing native, but it can be done with an SQL query – something like this should work (note that all the queries assume that your [`dbPrefix`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/db-settings.html#tableprefix) setting is set to `'craft_'`):

```
SELECT bt.id, bt.handle, f.handle as field 
FROM craft_matrixblocktypes bt 
INNER JOIN craft_fields f ON bt.fieldId = f.id 
LEFT JOIN craft_matrixblocks b ON bt.id = b.typeId 
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

The above query would output a table with the `id` and `handle` for all block types that aren't used, in addition to the handle for the Matrix field they belong to, i.e.

```
id  | handle             | field
------------------------------------------
13  | someMatrixBlock    | someMatrixField
4   | anotherMatrixBlock | someMatrixField
```

To actually execute the SQL query, you can use a free tool like [Sequel Pro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) or [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) – or [write a custom plugin](http://pluginfactory.io) that uses [the QueryBuilder](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/database).

**Edit**

Upon request in the comments below, here's a query that will list all block types that *are* in use (i.e. there are blocks for each particular block type). The number of blocks for each type is listed in a `count` column:

```
SELECT COUNT(bt.id) as count, bt.id, bt.handle, f.handle as field 
FROM craft_matrixblocktypes bt 
INNER JOIN craft_fields f ON bt.fieldId = f.id 
LEFT JOIN craft_matrixblocks b ON bt.id = b.typeId 
WHERE b.id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY bt.id
```

...and here's a query that will output a table with all blocks, sorted by block type, with the ID and URI for the entry which "owns" each particular block. The following query should work for Craft 2:

```
SELECT b.id as blockId, bt.handle as blockType, bt.id as blockTypeId, e.id as entryId, i18n.uri as entryUri, f.handle as field
FROM craft_matrixblocks b
INNER JOIN craft_entries e on e.id = b.ownerId
INNER JOIN craft_fields f on f.id = b.fieldId
INNER JOIN craft_matrixblocktypes bt on bt.id = b.typeId
LEFT JOIN craft_elements_i18n i18n on i18n.elementId = e.id
ORDER BY bt.id
```

**For Craft 3 (and 4)**, you'll need to replace the `craft_elements_i18n` table with `craft_elements_sites`:

```
SELECT b.id as blockId, bt.handle as blockType, bt.id as blockTypeId, e.id as entryId, sites.uri as entryUri, f.handle as field
FROM craft_matrixblocks b
INNER JOIN craft_entries e on e.id = b.ownerId
INNER JOIN craft_fields f on f.id = b.fieldId
INNER JOIN craft_matrixblocktypes bt on bt.id = b.typeId
LEFT JOIN craft_elements_sites sites on sites.elementId = e.id
ORDER BY bt.id
```

**If you want to exclude drafts, revisions and soft-deleted entries**, include this in the query:

```
INNER JOIN craft_elements els on els.id = b.ownerId 
WHERE els.dateDeleted IS NULL AND els.draftId IS NULL AND els.revisionId IS NULL AND els.archived = 0
```

**Edit: For Craft 4, you'll want to replace all instances of `b.ownerId` with `b.primaryOwnerId`.**

If you want to limit that last query to only list the blocks for a particular block type, you can replace the `ORDER BY` statement with this:

```
WHERE bt.id = 2
```

Where `2` is the ID for the block type you want to list.

Comment: Excellent - really useful - in a similar manner then is it possible to find the number of times a block from a particular field does appear and say what page it is on

Comment: The number of times a block type have been used (i.e. the number of blocks with that particular block type) should be easy enough, but if you want to output the ID/handle/URL for any elements with relevant blocks you're going to have to pull multiple rows for each block type (one per element), so I don't see those two operations being very useful together.

Comment: Thanks - the number of times of block type would be used would be very useful as we could see then what blocks we could do away with.
If there is a few then some way to find easily what entries the block is used in - even if it needed to be a separate query as there are a large number of entries on the site so could be hard to find manually

Comment: @mmc501 Edited my answer and added a couple queries that might prove useful.

Comment: First class - easy to tidy up now - much appreciated!

Comment: @mmc501The queries you provided are SUPER helpful. Just wanted to say thank you! You helped me considerably with this answer.

Comment: @dpayne Awesome that it proved helpful :)